# Azure Pipeline trigger on tags

Tags: azure-devops

I am making two pipelines. One will trigger on PR on Dev and Master branch. The another only trigger with new tags:
So for the first one, I have trigger:

```
pr:
  - master
  - dev
```

And the second one:

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'
    exclude:
    - master
    - dev
```

But the result is I have both triggered with PRs and the second first one is also triggered on CI. 
I have check there is no YAML overwrite on classic view. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 18):

> Azure Pipeline trigger on tags

If you want the second pipeline only trigger with new tags, you should set the parameter **`branches`** to exclude `master` and `dev` branch trigger.

So, the syntax should be like:

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - '*'
  branches:
    exclude:
    - master
    - dev
```

Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#ci-triggers) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The second pipeline still trigger on PR with your suggestion. But I went into classic view and overwrite yaml disabling trigger on PR. Now it only trigger on new tags. Thanks anyway

Comment: I want to achieve the same goal (second pipeline trigger only on tags), but the opposite behaviour: by allowing all tags in the trigger, the pipeline does not run when a tag is created. Tag is automatically created by semantic-release in a previous pipeline.

Comment: If i manually add the tag, the pipeline runs. Why the two ways to create tag have different behaviour?