# Azure Devops pipeline does not trigger on tags when they are created by semantic release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, semantic-release

I have two pipelines in an Azure Devops environment.

The first pipeline runs on branch `main` and does semantic versioning of the code: if fix or feat commits are present, it pushes another commit by changing the version in the proper file and also pushes the new tag (`v{major}.{minor}.{patch}`). This pipeline works fine. The semantic release process is managed through the python package `commitizen`.

The second pipeline builds a docker image. I want it to run only when the semantic-release tag is created. By reading the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tags), I think the correct trigger should be:

```
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - v*
```

This does not trigger the pipeline when the semantic-release tag is created. But it works if I manually create the tag.

I also tried to allow all tags (by including `'*'`), and also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63562354/16797805) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207712/16797805) solutions, again without success.

Why the manually created and semantic-release created tags behave differently? Am I missing something in the semantic-release or pipeline process functioning?

**EDIT:** I add the details of the semantic release pipeline.

```
trigger:
- main

variables:
  IS_MAIN: $[eq(variables['build.sourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]
  CI_USERNAME: "CI Bot"
  CI_EMAIL: ci-bot@azure.com

jobs:
- job: 'semantic_release'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  strategy:
    matrix:
      Python39:
        python.version: '3.9'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '$(python.version)'

  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: "0"
    persistCredentials: "true"
    clean: "true"

  - script: |
      git config --global user.email "$(CI_EMAIL)" && git config --global user.name "$(CI_USERNAME)"
      pip install commitizen
      cz bump --check-consistency --changelog --yes
      git push --tags origin HEAD:main
    condition: eq(variables.IS_MAIN, true)
    displayName: 'Bump package version number'
```

This is the relevant output of the `commitizen` semantic-release step:
[image]

Configuration for `commitizen` in `pyproject.toml` is the following (note in particular that the **`[skip ci]` message** is due to the config):

```
tag_format = "v$major.$minor.$patch"
annotated_tag = true
bump_message = "release $current_version -> $new_version [skip ci]"
```

Comment: Can you share the semantic release task & output?

Comment: Added details of pipeline and output for semantic-release

Comment: maybe is because the `[skip ci]` in the message? (it should skip ci trigger in commit but maybe it affect the tag as well)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! Removing `[skip ci]` causes the docker build pipeline to run correctly and the semantic-release pipeline to trigger another time on `main`, but the latter is a minor issue because it has no effect. If you post an answer for this I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: Great!! this is what I suspect in the beginning and so I wanted to see the semantic-release task :) I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `[skip ci]` from the commit message, because it pushed with the tag Azure DevOps skipping the ci.

You can find the list of "skip" messages [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).